# Limit of a infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\frac{2}{2} + \frac{2\cdot 5}{2\cdot 9} + \frac{2\cdot 5\cdot 10}{2\cdot 9\cdot 28} + \cdots + \frac{2\cdot 5\cdot 10 \cdots (n^2+1)}{2\cdot 9\cdot 28\cdots (n^3+1)}\tag1$$

For this series $(1)$, how would one go about applying the comparison test to check for convergence or divergence?

Comment: Apologies for my lack of knowledge, but the test has not yet been covered in any of my classes yet. Comparison, root and ratio test are all that I know how to apply. I would study the Raabe's test

Comment: So, the ratio test is applicable here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was off-point in thinking of Raabe's.

Comment: It comes as in conclusive as I get a value of 1 for the ratio

Comment: @ParasJoshi The ratio test gives $0$ as a limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general term of the series, $a_n$ is given by

$$a_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(k^2+1)}{(k^3+1)}$$

Then, we see that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^2+1}{(n+1)^3+1}\to 0\implies \text{the series converges}$$

Comment: The denominator is missing in the above calculation

Comment: The denominator is not missing.  $$\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}f_n=f_{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}f_n$$Hence$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}f_n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}f_n}=f_{n+1}$$

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. Complete mistake on my end.

Comment: Apology not necessary - no worry.  Pleased to see that you see it now.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge 3$ we get
$$\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+1}<\frac{n^2+1}{n^3}=\frac1n+\frac1{n^3}\le\frac13+\frac1{27}=\frac4{27}<\frac12$$
Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{j^2+1}{j^3+1}<1+\frac{5}{9}+\sum_{k=3}^n\frac59\left(\frac12\right)^{k-2}$$

So, by comparison test, we get that the given series converges.